# Returning multiple record IDs with an I-Descriptor

Tags: universe

Is it possible to create an I-descriptor that returns multiple record keys when the only the first part of the key is known? For example I have Quote Header record in the QTH file and need to reference all of the Quote Detail records in the QTD file.

A QTH record has an ID of '1159' so I know that all of the related QTD records will begin with '1159*'.

Entering `LIST QTD LIKE "1159*]"` returns

```
1159*D080*L*096*20
1159*D060*D*Shipping*
1159*D060*L*063*10
1159*D060*D*Dakota Sign*
1159*D080*L*092*30
```

I have tried a number of variations of the `TRANS()` statement in an I-Descriptor to return a multivalued list, all to no avail. Can this be done and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want an I-type in QTH to tell you the IDS in QTD that start with 1159.

You should be able to do this with a subroutine call.
The I-Type would be

1: I
2: SUBR("GETQTDIDS)
3: 
4: QTD-IDS
5: 10L
6: M

The subroutine would be:

SUBR GETQTDIDS(IDLIST)

EXECUTE "SELECT QTD WITH @ID LIKE ":(@ID):"..." CAPTURING IDLIST

RETURN
END

---

I would try something like that. Of course if you had an I-type in QTD which pulled out the first part of the @ID and indexed it you could use GETINDEX instead.

And of course if you had that its much easier to create an I-type in QTD which pulled information from QTH.

Comment: Thanks jbmonco. I suspected a subroutine would be required. I haven't yet had the need to do that but knew it was possible. Agree getting from a QTD to its parent QTH record is much easier but in this case based on a client request I would have to link in the 'wrong' direction.